# Newly created Django url's not working

Tags: python, django, url

The newly created Django url's are not warking. i can't figure out why these new urls are not working. I created the views and templates and then added them to my urls and I get the following error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/posts/dcma/
Raised by:  posts.views.post_detail
```

I don't understand why post_detail would be raising an issue.

heres my posts/urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import post_create, post_detail, \
post_list, post_update, \
post_delete, post_search, tag_list, \
search_title, display_hay, \
submit_video, privacy, terms, dcma

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
  url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
  url(r'^haystack/$', display_hay, name='haystack'),
  url(r'^search_f/$', search_title),
  url(r'^search_results/$', post_search, name='search-page'),
  url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),

  url(r'^submit_video/$', submit_video, name='submit_video'),
  url(r'^privacy/$', privacy, name='privacy'),
  url(r'^terms/$', terms, name='terms'),
  url(r'^dcma/$', dcma, name='dcma'),
# url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
]
```

my views .py

```
def display_hay(request):
all_results = SearchQuerySet().all()
template = "posts/display_hay.html"
context = {
    "all_results": all_results,
}
return render(request, template, context)


  def submit_video(request):
   template = "posts/submit_video.html"
   context = {
   }
   return render(request, template, context)


   def privacy(request):
   template = "posts/privacy.html"
   context = {
   }
   return render(request, template, context)


  def terms(request):
   template = "posts/terms.html"
   context = {
   }
   return render(request, template, context)


  def dcma(request):
   template = "posts/dcma.html"
   context = {
   }
   return render(request, template, context)
```

How can I correct my syntax? all guidance is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't know why It' was down voted. But the problem was caused the order of the url's. so instead of this

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
  url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
  url(r'^haystack/$', display_hay, name='haystack'),
  url(r'^search_f/$', search_title),
  url(r'^search_results/$', post_search, name='search-page'),
  url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),

  url(r'^submit_video/$', submit_video, name='submit_video'),
  url(r'^privacy/$', privacy, name='privacy'),
  url(r'^terms/$', terms, name='terms'),
  url(r'^dcma/$', dcma, name='dcma'),
# url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

it's this

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
   url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
   url(r'^dcma/$', dcma, name='dcma'),
   url(r'^submit_video/$', submit_video, name='submit_video'),
   url(r'^privacy/$', privacy, name='privacy'),
   url(r'^terms/$', terms, name='terms'),

   url(r'^haystack/$', display_hay, name='haystack'),
   url(r'^search_f/$', search_title),
   url(r'^search_results/$', post_search, name='search-page'),
   url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
   url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),
   # url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Django tries your urls in the order they are defined, and uses the first match. In this case, you have these urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
...

url(r'^submit_video/$', submit_video, name='submit_video'),
url(r'^privacy/$', privacy, name='privacy'),
url(r'^terms/$', terms, name='terms'),
url(r'^dcma/$', dcma, name='dcma'),
```

Any of the latter urls is also matched by the url pattern for the `post_detail` view. The `post_detail` view then tries to find a post that matches the slug, which it can't find, and raises a `Http404`. The views for the other patterns aren't called when the first matching views raises an error.

To fix this, you can do one of two things. Either you change the url pattern for `post_detail` so it doesn't conflict with the other patterns, or you move the last four patterns up, above the `post_detail` pattern. In the latter case, you can't use any of the conflicting urls as slugs for a post.